# sed or grep regex problem

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I am having difficulty using sed or grep to extract a piece of text from a string.

An example string I am using is:

```
|a Milton, John, |d 1608-1674.
```

I am able to extract 'John' using sed, and some advice on the forums:

```
sed 's/[^,]*,\([^,]*\),.*/\1/'
```

But I am struggling with 'Milton'.

Comment: Do all the input lines start with `|a `, or are there other possible contents?

Comment: "a|" is a constant, as is "d|". Obviously the name and dates vary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's the `|a` at the start of the line, let's change that pattern a bit:

```
$ echo '|a Milton, John, |d 1608-1674.' | sed -E 's/^\|a ([^,]*), *([^,]*),.*/\1/'
Milton
```

`sed -E` uses extended regexes, so we can group with `(...)` without backslashes. Then we match the leading `|a` and the space, pick everything up to the next comma to a group `([^,]*),`, ignore spaces with `␣*`, and pick another group the same way as the first. The `,.*` eats the rest of the line, and we can replace all of it with the first group `\1` (here `Milton`), or the second group `\2` (`John`).

Of course, if the `|a` is there to tell us what this particular field contains, and the fields might be in another order (like `|d ... |a ...`), then we'd need something different.